# Email body is empty, MIME multipart (text & html)

Tags: php, email, smtp

I can send just text fine, just html fine, but when I combine the two as follows the email sends but the body is empty.

```
$to = "some@email.com";
$subject = "Welcome";
$boundary = md5(date('U'));

$headers = "From: Company <noreply@email.com>" . "\n".
                   "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion() ."\n".
                   "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\n".
                   "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=".$boundary. "\n";
                   "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit". "\n";

// TEXT EMAIL PART
$text = "Congratulations";

// HTML EMAIL PART
$html = "<html><body>\n";
$html .= "<div>Congratulations</div>";
$html .= "</body></html>\n";

$message = "Multipart Message coming up" . "\n\n".
           "--".$boundary.
           "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"" .
           "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".
           $text. 
           "--".$boundary. 
           "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"". 
           "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit". 
           $html.
           "--".$boundary."--";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: i am assuming you have set $boundary to something?

Comment: also have a look at http://swiftmailer.org/ can do a lot of the hardwork for you

Comment: Yep its there now. Missed adding it when I cut and paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've forgotten line breaks after your Content-Type and Content-Transfer-Encoding  lines, so the beginnings of your body content are co-mingled with the headers:

```
       "--".$boundary.
                    ^^^--- missing \n
       "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".
                                        ^^^--- missing \n\n
       $text.
```

As stated in the comments above, use [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org) or [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com) to do this. They'll take care of all the piddle little details, and let you send the entire mail in far fewer lines of code.

Comment: Can't believe it was something that simple. I'll make sure to look at swiftmailer

Comment: For generating multi-line text like that, look into HEREDOCs as well. Much easier than repeated string concatenation. http://php.net/heredoc

Answer (score 0):

`$boundary` <del>is</del>was undefined, you don't have a line break before or after any of the boundaries, and you don't have a blank line between the headers and body of each part (or a line break after any of those headers).

Don't handroll MIME. I'm sure there is a decent library for PHP that will do it for you.

Comment: boundary's set on the 3rd line: md5(date('U'));

Comment: It wasn't when I wrote the answer. See the comments on the question.